# Why cant we initialize a FirebaseDatabase instance using the "new" keyword in Android (java)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I was reading up the documentation of Firebase Realtime Database for android. The docs say that we need to use the static method getInstance() of the FirebaseDatabase as an entry point to the Database. I was wondering as to why we cannot use the "new" keyword and manually code any configs that this static method was doing?

I haven't tried using new; just curious as to why/how static methods are provided as a replacement of constructors.

Comment: Factory methods have advantages over constructors. Most notably, it can maintain a singleton instance of the returned object for reuse and other optimizations.  Read the duplicate for a full generalized discussion.  Firebase adopts the use of factory methods on the whole as a design decision.